# Проблема с вариативным переходом по ссылке

Tags: reactjs, frontend, redux, react-router-dom

У меня есть компонент Header, в котором находится логотип-ссылка, поведение этой ссылки зависит от того на какой странице в данный момент находится пользователь, если на главной, то переход будет на страницу "/chooseWorkplace", если на какой-либо другой, то переход будет происходить на "/", т.е. главную страницу, почему при нажатии на логотип из другой страницы, меня сразу перебрасывает на страницу "/choosePlace"?
Код компонента:

```
function Header() {
    const navigate = useNavigate();
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const path = useLocation().pathname;

    const logoLink = path === "/" ? "/choosePlace" : "/";

    return (
        <HeaderContent path={path}>
            {!path.startsWith("/choosePlace") && (
                <img src={logo} className="logotype" onClick={() => {
                    dispatch(setSpot({ department: "", house: 0, floor: 0 }))
                    navigate(logoLink);
                }} />
            )}
        </HeaderContent>
    )
}
```